# I can't use my regular expression right

Tags: php, expression, preg-match-all

Sorry guys, maybe my question is really silly, but I'm stuck...again with regular expression...

**Look, I have a variable, for ex:**

```
$str = "[quote]Here I am 2013[/quote]";

$rega = preg_match_all("/[quote](.*)[quote]/i",$str,$hols);
```

**When I try to get $hols variable, I get something like this:**

quote]Here I am 2013[/quote

**But I need something like this:**

Here I am 2013

**Second question is When I try to get from $str:**

```
$str = "[quote]Hello people

this

is

my...[/quote]";
```

**So, with my regular expression, I get something like:**

```
quote]Hello people
```

**But I need:**

```
Hello people

this

is

my...
```

I'd really appreciate if you could explain to me how to handle with it, how to make it right. Because I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Frits has said, you need to escape the brackets; you are currently asking the RegEx to match any of the characters 'q', 'u', 'o', 't' or 'e', followed by anything, followed by those same characters again; the only reason the match is as large as it is has to do with the fact that your expression was greedy, while Frits' suggestion would "break" this (correctly, though).  In short, escape the brackets like so:

```
/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/mis
```

#### More explanation:

Considering your earlier pattern:

```
/[quote](.*)[quote]/i
```

You are asking for:

1. Any character of the set [quote]
2. Any character except a newline, zero or more times
3. Any character of the set [quote]

So, for example, the string `Queen's Charter!` would match, as `Queen's Charte` with an inner match of `ueen's Chart` (since the first and last character class are not captured).

If you make the second step non-greedy, then you get `Qu`, `ee`, and `te`, with no inner matches at all.

### Edit: Replying to comment

I ran the following code:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/mis',
    "[quote]A test!  A Marvelous Test![/quote]",
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches);
```

And got the following result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '[quote]A test!  A Marvelous Test![/quote]' (length=41)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'A test!  A Marvelous Test!' (length=26)
```

Comment: sorry, but your variant is not working, it still return smth like: [quote]Hello people this is my...[/quote] with  [quote] I mean

Comment: Are you looking in `$hols[0]` or `$hols[1]`?  `$hols[0]` will contain **full** matches, i.e. the whole string; `$hols[1]` will contain the **subpattern** (the part in parentheses, between the quote tags).  See my recent edits for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("/[quote](.*)[quote]/i",$str,$hols);
                             ^--- missing / there
```

Also, you probably want:

```
"/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/mis"
```

To make it: ungreedy, match multiple lines, and you must escape the `[` and `]` as `[quote]` actually defines a character class matching just q, u, o, t and e

If you can also nest `[quote]`s you have to step away from using regular expressions, because nesting is not context-free. Regular expressions can only deal with context-free grammars. The solution then is to build a (very simple) parser.

Comment: +1 for parsers; never nest regular expressions.  If you think you can, you can't.  This way, madness lies.